# How to create, in code behind, a Custom MessageBox with Images in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, messagebox

How to create, in code behind (with no XAML), a custom MessageBox (Dialog Boxes) in WPF C#? 
I googled it and seems not to find a solution. I would want to have a MessageBox with Images and other Controls add to it.

Comment: Have you tried using the Popup WPF control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this solution:

```
    string messageBoxText = "Do you want to save changes?";
    string caption = "Your caption";
    MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
    MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
```

look over [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx) article, you my recode all Xaml into pure c# in Custom Dialog Boxes paragraph if you want.

or you may create your own Window and use `MyWindow.ShowDialog()`.

Like in this code:

```
    Window wnd = new Window();
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    wnd.Height = 200;
    wnd.Width = 150;
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(100) });
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto });
    wnd.Content = grid;
    Image img = new Image();
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Content = "OK";
    btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    Grid.SetRow(img, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(btn, 1); 
    grid.Children.Add(img);
    grid.Children.Add(btn);
    wnd.Owner = MyMainWindow;
    wnd.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create your custom Window in XAML and then use showDialog() in code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

Everything from XAML can be rewrited in pure c#:

```
<Window>
 <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
  <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="*">
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello World!" />
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

will looks like this:

```
public void MakeWin(DependencyObject owner)
{
   MakeWin(Window.GetWindow(owner));
}

public void MakeWin(Window owner)
{
   Window window = new Window();
   Grid grid = new Grid();
   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50) });
   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Auto});
   window.Content = grid;

   Label label = new Label { Content = "Hello World!" };
   Grid.SetColumn(label, 0); // Depandency property
   grid.Children.Add(label);

   window.Owner = owner;
   window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For images, there is source code (or a prebuilt one) for you in the WPF toolkit http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox&version=31

If you need more than an image, a line of text and a couple of buttons, then you should probably start looking at just using a new Window invoked with ShowDialog()

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a WPF MessageBox that has the exact same interface has the normal one and is also fully customizable via standard WPF control templates:

[A Customizable WPF MessageBox](https://web.archive.org/web/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox/)

**Features**

- The class WPFMessageBox has the exact same interface as the current WPF MessageBox class.
- Implemented as a custom control, thus fully customizable via standard WPF control templates.
- Has a default control template which looks like the standard MessageBox.
- Supports all the common types of message boxes: Error, Warning, Question and Information.
- Has the same “Beep” sounds as when opening a standard MessageBox.
- Supports the same behavior when pressing the Escape button as the standard MessageBox.
- Provides the same system menu as the standard MessageBox, including disabling the Close button when the message box is in Yes-No mode.
- Handles right-aligned and right-to-left operating systems, same as the standard MessageBox.
- Provides support for setting the owner window as a WinForms Form control.